# How to update rows in one column of a Table with increment number in minus in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have to update around 40 rows in a column of a table with increment of numbers in minus i.e -1,-2,-3,-4 etc in sybase ASE. Can any one tell how to do

Comment: What does the table look like? What column should be updated? Please add some more detail to the question.

Comment: Its a normal table. I just want to update the null values of the rows (for one column) to -1, -2, -3... etc i.e., auto increment with minus symbol

Answer (score 0):

Raj, identity values in ASE cannot be set to maintain a sequence of negative values as you want. So that eliminates the simplest approach.

Let's assume your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id     not null,
  name   varchar(20),
  serial int null
)
```

where `serial` is the column that may contain NULL values.

You could create a trigger on the table to update `serial` when it is null.

Alternatively if you are trying to update existing values in this table you could run the following code 40 times:

```
UPDATE  cars
SET     serial = -(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars WHERE serial IS NULL)
WHERE   id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cars WHERE serial IS NULL)
```

Of course, for 40 rows manually updating the values sounds attractive!